# jQuery: how to select every cell in a table except the last in each row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want every cell in each row except the last in each row.  I tried:

```
$("table tr td:not(:last)")
```

but that seems to have given me every cell except the very last in the table.  Not quite what I want.

I'm sure this is simple but I'm still wrapping my head around the selectors.

Comment: are you sure you shouldn't be using a `<tfoot>` instead? then only match tbody-rows.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try:

```
$('table tr td:not(:last-child)')
```

Comment: From the documentation: While :last matches only a single element, this matches more then one: One for each parent.

Comment: And the winner by chronological order... :)

Answer (score 7):

You could try

```
$("table td:not(:last-child)")
```

or

```
$("table td:not(:nth-child(n))")
```

where n is 1-based index of a child element

or

```
$("table td").not(":last-child")
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the last-child selector. This:

```
$("table tr td:not(:last-child)")
```

will select all cells in all rows except of the cells in the last column.

Comment: the tr is unnecessary as by default jquery does not look for immediate descendants - to get the immediate descendants only, you need to use the > "operator"

Answer (score 0):

fwiw I found your original works just fine (maybe an enhancement to main jQ since 2009?)...

```
$("#myTable thead th:not(:last)").css("border-right","1px solid white");
```

The header row of my table has navy background so the white border on the right made the table look snaggletoothed and not match the black 1px border of the data